# "Stop on Error" Option for mochajs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm running some tests with mochajs.

```
var Mocha = require('mocha');
var mocha = new Mocha();
mocha.addFile('mocha/0000_1234.js');
mocha.addFile('mocha/0010_5678.js');

mocha.run(function(failures){
...
```

Is there an option like "Stop on Error"?
I want to stop my tests, when the first error happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `bail` option:

> bail after first test failure

To set this option, use `mocha#setup` method:

```
mocha.setup({
  bail: true
});
```

[Mocha docs](https://mochajs.org/#usage)